# mysql php field value wiht quotes won't select

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function for selecting from my database but when the $id contains quotes it breaks. Here is my code:

```
public function database_select_one($table, $identifier, $id) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$identifier.'="'.$id.'" LIMIT 1';
    $mysqli_result = $this->query($sql);
    $data = $this->fetch($mysqli_result, 1);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: have you tried simple quotes? $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$identifier.'='."'".$id."' LIMIT 1';

Comment: i put doubles around again and it didnt work like so SELECT * FROM ATABLE WHERE $identifier = ""$id"" I guess it doesn't work because the entire value isn't in quotes, just part of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove quotes from you **$id** field with `str_replace`. https://www.php.net/str_replace

```
public function database_select_one($table, $identifier, $id) {
    str_replace('"', "", $id);
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$identifier.'="'.$id.'" LIMIT 1';
    $mysqli_result = $this->query($sql);
    $data = $this->fetch($mysqli_result, 1);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: it won't select the article without the quotes, the quotes are part of the value, like if an article is named This Aricle "Has Quotes"

Comment: Are using both single and double quotes in data?

Comment: well I have to say I don't know, it's part of a CMS for clients and I don't know what they will use, it has to be either/and/or

Comment: Then you should use Kikov's solution

Comment: kikov's solution worked and so did this: $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_mysqli, $id);

Comment: when I said that Kikov's answer didn't work I mistyped his comment, thank you for the help Kikov and Mahmut

Answer (score 0):

Use prepare statement:

```
$stmt= mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE ". $identifier . " = :id LIMIT 1");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "id", $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I've been meaning to get to prepared statements for some time now, I guess it's not as complicated as everyone makes it out to be